# Elastic Search: The SSL connection could not be established when connecting to enterprise serch

Tags: c#, docker, elasticsearch, c#-6.0

I have deployed an ELK cluster using docker on my machine, a macbook running Monterey. I am trying to index some documents by sending a http request to the enterprise search node, but I am getting an error regarding the SSL connection.

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: "2.2"

services:
    setup:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
        volumes:
            - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
        user: "0"
        command: >
            bash -c '
              if [ x${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
                echo "Set the ELASTIC_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
                exit 1;
              elif [ x${KIBANA_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
                echo "Set the KIBANA_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
                exit 1;
              fi;
              if [ ! -f certs/ca.zip ]; then
                echo "Creating CA";
                bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --silent --pem -out config/certs/ca.zip;
                unzip config/certs/ca.zip -d config/certs;
              fi;
              if [ ! -f certs/certs.zip ]; then
                echo "Creating certs";
                echo -ne \
                "instances:\n"\
                "  - name: es01\n"\
                "    dns:\n"\
                "      - es01\n"\
                "      - localhost\n"\
                "    ip:\n"\
                "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
                > config/certs/instances.yml;
                bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem -out config/certs/certs.zip --in config/certs/instances.yml --ca-cert config/certs/ca/ca.crt --ca-key config/certs/ca/ca.key;
                unzip config/certs/certs.zip -d config/certs;
              fi;
              echo "Setting file permissions"
              chown -R root:root config/certs;
              find . -type d -exec chmod 750 \{\} \;;
              find . -type f -exec chmod 640 \{\} \;;
              echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch availability";
              until curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://es01:9200 | grep -q "missing authentication credentials"; do sleep 30; done;
              echo "Setting kibana_system password";
              until curl -s -X POST --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt -u elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://es01:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"${KIBANA_PASSWORD}\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;
              echo "All done!";
            '
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "[ -f config/certs/es01/es01.crt ]" ]
            interval: 1s
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 120

    es01:
        depends_on:
            setup:
                condition: service_healthy
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
        volumes:
            - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
            - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        ports:
            - ${ES_PORT}:9200
        environment:
            - node.name=es01
            - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
            - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01
            - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
            - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
            - xpack.security.enabled=true
            - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
            - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
            - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
            - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
            - xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
            - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
            - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
            - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
            - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
            - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
            - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
        mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
        ulimits:
            memlock:
                soft: -1
                hard: -1
        healthcheck:
            test:
                [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'"
                ]
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 10s
            retries: 120

    kibana:
        depends_on:
            es01:
                condition: service_healthy
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
        volumes:
            - certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
            - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
        ports:
            - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
        environment:
            - SERVERNAME=kibana
            - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://es01:9200
            - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
            - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
            - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=config/certs/ca/ca.crt
            - ENTERPRISESEARCH_HOST=http://enterprisesearch:${ENTERPRISE_SEARCH_PORT}
        mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
        healthcheck:
            test:
                [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'"
                ]
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 10s
            retries: 120

    enterprisesearch:
        depends_on:
            es01:
                condition: service_healthy
            kibana:
                condition: service_healthy
        image: docker.elastic.co/enterprise-search/enterprise-search:${STACK_VERSION}
        volumes:
            - certs:/usr/share/enterprise-search/config/certs
            - enterprisesearchdata:/usr/share/enterprise-search/config
        ports:
            - ${ENTERPRISE_SEARCH_PORT}:3002
        environment:
            - SERVERNAME=enterprisesearch
            - secret_management.encryption_keys=[${ENCRYPTION_KEYS}]
            - allow_es_settings_modification=true
            - elasticsearch.host=https://es01:9200
            - elasticsearch.username=elastic
            - elasticsearch.password=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
            - elasticsearch.ssl.enabled=true
            - elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authority=/usr/share/enterprise-search/config/certs/ca/ca.crt
            - kibana.external_url=http://kibana:5601
        mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
        healthcheck:
            test:
                [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "curl -s -I http://localhost:3002 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'"
                ]
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 10s
            retries: 120

volumes:
    certs:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            type: 'none'
            o: 'bind'
            device: ${HOSTCERTSDIR}
    enterprisesearchdata:
        driver: local
    esdata01:
        driver: local
    kibanadata:
        driver: local
```

And this is how I am creating the ElasticSearchClient:

```
private void CreateElasticSearchObject(string URI, string certificateFingerprint, string apiKey, int timeOut)
{

  var settings = new ElasticsearchClientSettings(new Uri(URI))
                     .CertificateFingerprint(certificateFingerprint)
                     .Authentication(new ApiKey(apiKey));

  settings.ThrowExceptions(alwaysThrow: true);
  settings.PrettyJson();
  settings.RequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeOut));

  ElasticSearch.ElasticClient = new ElasticsearchClient(settings);
}
```

When I run `ElasticClient.Ping()` I get the follow error:

```
    Exception has occurred: CLR/Elastic.Transport.TransportException
    Exception thrown: 'Elastic.Transport.TransportException' in Elastic.Transport.dll: 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Call: Status code unknown from: HEAD /?pretty=true'
     Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
     Innermost exception     System.IO.IOException : Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.
       at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GetFrameSize(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)
       at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<ReceiveBlobAsync>d__176`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<ForceAuthenticationAsync>d__175`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.<EstablishSslConnectionAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

The certificate is self signed and was created by the docker container using Elastic Searchs buitin tool. I also have imported it to my keychain (on my local machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I was using the wrong api key. The code works fine.